# Email/MIME parser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parsing

I need to parse EML files within a Cocoa app. Are there some Objective-C libs which can handle this for me?

The files include formatted text and attachments so this should be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't find any objective-c library but google provided me with http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html it does the job.

Comment: How did you add this library to your Objective-c / Xcode project?